# What status code represents : POST failed to edit because too many entries?

Tags: http-status-codes

400 error codes confuse me and I'm not sure which this corresponds to! What status code represents : POST failed to edit because too many entries?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `429 Too Many Requests` HTTP status code. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)